# ActiveStorage::InvariableError in Home#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

Currently I'm trying to display `.HEIC` images in Rails 6. I'm using [ActiveStorage ImageMagic](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html) to use variant to display `jpg`. Basically I'm trying to use

```
mogrify -format jpg myimage.heic
```

In the image to display `jpg`.

I added `Rails.application.config.active_storage.variant_processor` into application.rb to be able to use the variant. However it seems to break in the following line:

```
 <%= image_tag post.image.variant(format: 'jpg'), class: "card-home__img" %>
```

Why is not working?

Answer (score 11):

You can only call `variant` on an image that returns `true` when you call `variable?` on it.

Internally, `ActiveStorage` checks if `ActiveStorage.variable_content_types` contains your image's type. The default supported values are:

- `image/png`
- `image/gif`
- `image/jpg`
- `image/jpeg`
- `image/pjpeg`
- `image/tiff`
- `image/bmp`
- `image/vnd.adobe.photoshop`
- `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`
- `image/webp`

So it seems that currently .HEIC images are not supported.

You can instead apply a format transformation before attaching the image to a model or storing it, it might solve your use case.

Comment: This worked for me. Any idea what `.variable?` means. Seems like a weird choice kinda unrelated to what it actually does

Comment: @stevec According to a comment in the source code it just checks if ImageMagick can transform it, maybe they were thinking about image variations, hence the name.

``` ruby
def variable?
  ActiveStorage.variable_content_types.include?(content_type)
end
```
[You can check the source code here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/914caca2d31bd753f47f9168f2a375921d9e91cc/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob/representable.rb#L42).

Comment: Thanks Juan! Today I encountered a seemingly regular `.png` that couldn't be transformed for some reason. I will read the github code. Thanks!

Comment: @stevec Sure thing. Supposedly ActiveStorage should be able to work with .png, but I've seen it behave weird from time to time. If you need to check the supported types you can find them [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/45d1efab5163f030a1a8555d44ab11b4cd437d13/activestorage/lib/active_storage/engine.rb#L31) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this! I had a file with a `.jpeg` extension that was throwing this exception, and after investigating the image a bit more discovered that it was actually an HEIC image disguised as a jpeg. This answer helped me narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Raised when `ActiveStorage::Blob#variant` is called on a blob that isn't variable. Use `ActiveStorage::Blob#variable?` to determine whether a blob is variable.

**Source**: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/InvariableError.html