# Query for all users who have ".variable?" Active Storage image attachment(s)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52507141/5783745) helpful answer on [How to query records that have an ActiveStorage attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418114/how-to-query-records-that-have-an-activestorage-attachment)

I am trying to query for all Users who have at least one image (easy to adapt related question, see below), ***and*** whose first image is `.variable?`

#### What I know so far

This returns all users who have at least one image

```
User.
  left_joins(:images_attachments).
  group(:id).
  having("COUNT(active_storage_attachments) > 0")
```

But I'm not sure how to return just the users whose first image is `.variable?` (i.e. users whose image won't error when its size is changed)

Comment: How's `variable?` defined?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I'm not exactly sure, it's not mentioned in the [Rails Guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) on Active Storage, however, there's a basic description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61971660/5783745) (basically it means rails can change the size of the image - for example if someone accidentally uploaded a `.pdf` as their profile pic, then `.variable?` would return false, but for most image types, it returns true)

Answer (score 3):

As `variable?` is defined in the `ActiveStorage::Blob::Representable` module, you should load every `ActiveStorage::Blob` object and check what's the value the method returns when invoked on it. But I think that could remain as the last alternative.

Knowing that what the `variable?` method does is just to check whether the blob `content_type` is one of the predefined ones in `ActiveStorage.variable_content_types`, you could try doing that, but using SQL:

```
User.left_joins(:main_image_attachment)
    .joins('INNER JOIN active_storage_blobs ON active_storage_blobs.id = active_storage_attachments.blob_id')
    .group(:id)
    .having('COUNT(active_storage_attachments.id) > 0')
    .where(active_storage_blobs: { content_type: ActiveStorage.variable_content_types })
```

So you do almost the same, but just bring the `active_storage_blobs` table into memory to get access to the `content_type` column.

Comment: Doesn't the INNER JOIN guarantee `'COUNT(active_storage_attachments.id) > 0'`?

Comment: Indeed, good catch, but you'll need to add the joins with `main_image_attachment` as well to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to query for all Users who have at least one image (easy to adapt related question, see below), and whose first image is .variable?

You want `Users who have at least one image`, so `INNER JOIN` should be ok.

If you want `whose first image` literally, this could by achieved by `join subquery`.

And combine the answer of @SebastianPalma, we could do it like this:

```rb
# Query for attachments with just first image of users
subquery = ActiveStorage::Attachment.where(record_type: 'User')
                                    .order(:record_id, created_at: :asc)
                                    .select('DISTINCT ON (record_id) *')
                                    .to_sql

User.joins("INNER JOIN (#{subquery}) AS active_storage_attachments ON active_storage_attachments.id = users.id")
    .joins('INNER JOIN active_storage_blobs ON active_storage_blobs.id = active_storage_attachments.blob_id')
    .where(active_storage_blobs: { content_type: ActiveStorage.variable_content_types })
```